# how can i add the stock and totalprice whenever their is duplicate in a product?

Tags: c#

```
    private void btnSaveOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double tps = Convert.ToDouble(txtStockOut.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtPriceOut.Text);
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;UID=root;Database=db_cignal");
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "update inventoryOut set Model=@Model,Stock=@Stock,Date=@Date,Price=@Price,TotalPrice=@Total where Product=@Product";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", cbProductOut.SelectedItem.ToString());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", txtModelOut.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stock", txtStockOut.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtPriceOut.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", tps.ToString());
            command.Prepare();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            BindGridInventoryOut();
            ClearFieldsinInventoryOUT();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: hmm given that product in the inventory out is primary. what i wanted to do is eveytime i hit the save btn i want to updated the records, if i want to update the record which is already at the DB, i want to add its stocks, total price, and change the date.

Comment: oww thanks Soner for that advice :)

Comment: Have a look at `merge`. It sounds like you could use that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give it a try even if it's unclear. You want to update the table by adding the stock and totalprice to the already available values.

Then this should work:

```
string sql = @"update inventoryOut set 
                  Model=@Model,
                  Stock=@Stock,
                  Date=@Date,
                  Price=Price + @Price,
                  TotalPrice=TotalPrice + @Total 
               where Product=@Product";
command.CommandText = sql;
```

Apart from that, why do you use `string` for columns like `Price` or `Total`? Don't use `AddWithValue` but `Add` and pass the correct  `SqlDbType`. For example:

```
decimal price = decimal.Parse(txtPriceOut.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = price;
```